# How to merge two tables with same values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, Table1 and Table2.

**Table1** has the columns "*ID*","*Date*" and **Table2** has the columns "*ID*", "*Cost*".

Now, the way I want to merge these two tables into a new table **Table3** with columns "*ID*", "*Date*", "*Cost*" is that the *Cost* and *Date* are in the same row which have the same *ID* in both Table2 and Table1 respectively.

In short, I want to glue the two tables with respect to a column, in this case "*ID*".

I've looked into statements like `INSERT INTO TABLE`  but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform an insert-select on the result of the join between the two source tables:

```
CREATE TABLE table3 AS
SELECT table1.id AS id, date, cost
FROM   table1
JOIN   table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: I'm performing this query on a database with around 1.2 Million rows. Its been running for around 2 minutes now. I hope I didnt crash the server. Since I'm not very comfortable with database management. I wanted to script this in python to combine the tables. But I reckon, this should be faster than an external script?

Comment: Update: Has been running for around 10 minutes now. Should I be worried? :P Unable to access the database as well.

Comment: I restarted the server to interupt the process but there doesnt seem to have been added any new table. Is the query right?

Answer (score 0):

please use below SQL to merge

insert into table3 (id, date1, cost) 
select a.id, b.date1, a.cost from table1 a, table2 b where a.id=b.id;